# Rendering bug kernel freezes Electron App on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, electron, raspbian

I'm building an Electron application running on Raspberry Pi 2 and I'm facing a problem. My Electron version is 1.3.14.

The application is a main window that instantiate a new window to show something and then close it to come back to the main window.

The app is working most of the time for 5 days without problems and then randomly the app freezes and all the OS is frozen too.

My application logging system doesn't throw any software error but I found some error log in the system log:

Here here the part of the log with the errors. We can see a first error is related to the **CompositorTileW** process.

```
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.591701] BUG: Bad page state in process CompositorTileW  pfn:03492
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.591843] BUG: Bad page state in process CompositorTileW  pfn:034aa
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.591851] page:ba01c7e8 count:0 mapcount:0 mapping:0a000000 index:0x1
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.591858] flags: 0x0()
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.591860] page dumped because: non-NULL mapping
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.591926] Modules linked in: bnep bluetooth ppp_deflate zlib_deflate bsd_comp ppp_async crc_ccitt ppp_generic slhc cfg80211 rfkill sg option usb_wwan usbserial snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_timer snd bcm2835_gpiomem spi_bcm2835 bcm2835_wdt lirc_rpi(C) uio_pdrv_genirq uio lirc_dev rc_core i2c_dev fuse ipv6
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.591937] CPU: 1 PID: 1318 Comm: CompositorTileW Tainted: G         C      4.4.34-v7+ #930
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.591940] Hardware name: BCM2709
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.591975] [<80018784>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<80014058>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.591991] [<80014058>] (show_stack) from [<803215c4>] (dump_stack+0xd4/0x118)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592006] [<803215c4>] (dump_stack) from [<80103874>] (bad_page+0xdc/0x12c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592020] [<80103874>] (bad_page) from [<801071a8>] (get_page_from_freelist+0x3bc/0xb5c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592033] [<801071a8>] (get_page_from_freelist) from [<80107c38>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x150/0x9e0)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592045] [<80107c38>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask) from [<8012ea4c>] (handle_mm_fault+0xe0c/0x112c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592058] [<8012ea4c>] (handle_mm_fault) from [<805bc808>] (do_page_fault+0x340/0x3b4)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592069] [<805bc808>] (do_page_fault) from [<800091e8>] (do_DataAbort+0x48/0xc4)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592079] [<800091e8>] (do_DataAbort) from [<805bc0e4>] (__dabt_usr+0x44/0x60)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592083] Exception stack(0xa827bfb0 to 0xa827bff8)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592089] bfa0:                                     03206000 00000000 000077f0 00000000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592097] bfc0: 7166e154 0003d800 0003d800 7166e148 00000400 00000002 00000005 02f1e600
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592104] bfe0: 00000000 7166e130 00000000 76f5b0dc 20000010 ffffffff
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592108] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592159] BUG: Bad page state in process CompositorTileW  pfn:034ae
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592167] page:ba01c878 count:0 mapcount:0 mapping:80000000 index:0x1
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592171] flags: 0x0()
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592173] page dumped because: non-NULL mapping
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592223] Modules linked in: bnep bluetooth ppp_deflate zlib_deflate bsd_comp ppp_async crc_ccitt ppp_generic slhc cfg80211 rfkill sg option usb_wwan usbserial snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_timer snd bcm2835_gpiomem spi_bcm2835 bcm2835_wdt lirc_rpi(C) uio_pdrv_genirq uio lirc_dev rc_core i2c_dev fuse ipv6
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592230] CPU: 1 PID: 1318 Comm: CompositorTileW Tainted: G    B    C      4.4.34-v7+ #930
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592232] Hardware name: BCM2709
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592247] [<80018784>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<80014058>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592258] [<80014058>] (show_stack) from [<803215c4>] (dump_stack+0xd4/0x118)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592269] [<803215c4>] (dump_stack) from [<80103874>] (bad_page+0xdc/0x12c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592282] [<80103874>] (bad_page) from [<801071a8>] (get_page_from_freelist+0x3bc/0xb5c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592293] [<801071a8>] (get_page_from_freelist) from [<80107c38>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x150/0x9e0)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592305] [<80107c38>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask) from [<8012ea4c>] (handle_mm_fault+0xe0c/0x112c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592315] [<8012ea4c>] (handle_mm_fault) from [<805bc808>] (do_page_fault+0x340/0x3b4)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592326] [<805bc808>] (do_page_fault) from [<800091e8>] (do_DataAbort+0x48/0xc4)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592335] [<800091e8>] (do_DataAbort) from [<805bc0e4>] (__dabt_usr+0x44/0x60)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592338] Exception stack(0xa827bfb0 to 0xa827bff8)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592346] bfa0:                                     03209000 00000000 000047f0 00000000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592355] bfc0: 7166e154 0003d800 0003d800 7166e148 00000400 00000002 00000005 02f1e600
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592361] bfe0: 00000000 7166e130 00000000 76f5b0dc 20000010 ffffffff
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592413] BUG: Bad page state in process CompositorTileW  pfn:034b2
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592419] page:ba01c908 count:0 mapcount:0 mapping:08000000 index:0x1
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592423] flags: 0x0()
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592425] page dumped because: non-NULL mapping
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592476] Modules linked in: bnep bluetooth ppp_deflate zlib_deflate bsd_comp ppp_async crc_ccitt ppp_generic slhc cfg80211 rfkill sg option usb_wwan usbserial snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_timer snd bcm2835_gpiomem spi_bcm2835 bcm2835_wdt lirc_rpi(C) uio_pdrv_genirq uio lirc_dev rc_core i2c_dev fuse ipv6
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592483] CPU: 1 PID: 1318 Comm: CompositorTileW Tainted: G    B    C      4.4.34-v7+ #930
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592485] Hardware name: BCM2709
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592500] [<80018784>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<80014058>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592511] [<80014058>] (show_stack) from [<803215c4>] (dump_stack+0xd4/0x118)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592521] [<803215c4>] (dump_stack) from [<80103874>] (bad_page+0xdc/0x12c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592533] [<80103874>] (bad_page) from [<801071a8>] (get_page_from_freelist+0x3bc/0xb5c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592545] [<801071a8>] (get_page_from_freelist) from [<80107c38>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x150/0x9e0)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592557] [<80107c38>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask) from [<8012ea4c>] (handle_mm_fault+0xe0c/0x112c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592566] [<8012ea4c>] (handle_mm_fault) from [<805bc808>] (do_page_fault+0x340/0x3b4)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592574] [<805bc808>] (do_page_fault) from [<800091e8>] (do_DataAbort+0x48/0xc4)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592583] [<800091e8>] (do_DataAbort) from [<805bc0e4>] (__dabt_usr+0x44/0x60)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592586] Exception stack(0xa827bfb0 to 0xa827bff8)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592593] bfa0:                                     0320c000 00000000 000017f0 00000000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592601] bfc0: 7166e154 0003d800 0003d800 7166e148 00000400 00000002 00000005 02f1e600
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.592608] bfe0: 00000000 7166e130 00000000 76f5b0dc 20000010 ffffffff
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600292] BUG: Bad page state in process CompositorTileW  pfn:034c1
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600303] page:ba01cb24 count:0 mapcount:0 mapping:08000000 index:0x1
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600312] flags: 0x0()
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600315] page dumped because: non-NULL mapping
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600380] Modules linked in: bnep bluetooth ppp_deflate zlib_deflate bsd_comp ppp_async crc_ccitt ppp_generic slhc cfg80211 rfkill sg option usb_wwan usbserial snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_timer snd bcm2835_gpiomem spi_bcm2835 bcm2835_wdt lirc_rpi(C) uio_pdrv_genirq uio lirc_dev rc_core i2c_dev fuse ipv6
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600391] CPU: 1 PID: 1318 Comm: CompositorTileW Tainted: G    B    C      4.4.34-v7+ #930
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600394] Hardware name: BCM2709
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600432] [<80018784>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<80014058>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600449] [<80014058>] (show_stack) from [<803215c4>] (dump_stack+0xd4/0x118)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600465] [<803215c4>] (dump_stack) from [<80103874>] (bad_page+0xdc/0x12c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600480] [<80103874>] (bad_page) from [<801071a8>] (get_page_from_freelist+0x3bc/0xb5c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600492] [<801071a8>] (get_page_from_freelist) from [<80107c38>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x150/0x9e0)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600504] [<80107c38>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask) from [<8012ea4c>] (handle_mm_fault+0xe0c/0x112c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600515] [<8012ea4c>] (handle_mm_fault) from [<805bc808>] (do_page_fault+0x340/0x3b4)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600528] [<805bc808>] (do_page_fault) from [<800091e8>] (do_DataAbort+0x48/0xc4)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600537] [<800091e8>] (do_DataAbort) from [<805bc0e4>] (__dabt_usr+0x44/0x60)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600541] Exception stack(0xa827bfb0 to 0xa827bff8)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600548] bfa0:                                     031da000 00000000 000337f0 00000000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600557] bfc0: 7166e154 0003d800 0003d800 7166e148 00000400 00000002 00000005 02f1e600
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600564] bfe0: 00000000 7166e130 00000000 76f5b0dc 20000010 ffffffff
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600940] BUG: Bad page state in process CompositorTileW  pfn:034de
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600946] page:ba01cf38 count:0 mapcount:0 mapping:80000000 index:0x1
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600950] flags: 0x0()
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.600953] page dumped because: non-NULL mapping
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601002] Modules linked in: bnep bluetooth ppp_deflate zlib_deflate bsd_comp ppp_async crc_ccitt ppp_generic slhc cfg80211 rfkill sg option usb_wwan usbserial snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_timer snd bcm2835_gpiomem spi_bcm2835 bcm2835_wdt lirc_rpi(C) uio_pdrv_genirq uio lirc_dev rc_core i2c_dev fuse ipv6
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601010] CPU: 1 PID: 1318 Comm: CompositorTileW Tainted: G    B    C      4.4.34-v7+ #930
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601012] Hardware name: BCM2709
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601027] [<80018784>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<80014058>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601038] [<80014058>] (show_stack) from [<803215c4>] (dump_stack+0xd4/0x118)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601049] [<803215c4>] (dump_stack) from [<80103874>] (bad_page+0xdc/0x12c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601062] [<80103874>] (bad_page) from [<801071a8>] (get_page_from_freelist+0x3bc/0xb5c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601074] [<801071a8>] (get_page_from_freelist) from [<80107c38>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x150/0x9e0)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601085] [<80107c38>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask) from [<8012ea4c>] (handle_mm_fault+0xe0c/0x112c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601094] [<8012ea4c>] (handle_mm_fault) from [<805bc808>] (do_page_fault+0x340/0x3b4)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601102] [<805bc808>] (do_page_fault) from [<800091e8>] (do_DataAbort+0x48/0xc4)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601111] [<800091e8>] (do_DataAbort) from [<805bc0e4>] (__dabt_usr+0x44/0x60)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601115] Exception stack(0xa827bfb0 to 0xa827bff8)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601121] bfa0:                                     031f6000 00000000 000177f0 00000000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601129] bfc0: 7166e154 0003d800 0003d800 7166e148 00000400 00000002 00000005 02f1e600
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601135] bfe0: 00000000 7166e130 00000000 76f5b0dc 20000010 ffffffff
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601294] BUG: Bad page state in process CompositorTileW  pfn:034ea
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601299] page:ba01d0e8 count:0 mapcount:0 mapping:08000000 index:0x1
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601303] flags: 0x0()
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601306] page dumped because: non-NULL mapping
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601355] Modules linked in: bnep bluetooth ppp_deflate zlib_deflate bsd_comp ppp_async crc_ccitt ppp_generic slhc cfg80211 rfkill sg option usb_wwan usbserial snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_timer snd bcm2835_gpiomem spi_bcm2835 bcm2835_wdt lirc_rpi(C) uio_pdrv_genirq uio lirc_dev rc_core i2c_dev fuse ipv6
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601364] CPU: 1 PID: 1318 Comm: CompositorTileW Tainted: G    B    C      4.4.34-v7+ #930
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601366] Hardware name: BCM2709
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601379] [<80018784>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<80014058>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601390] [<80014058>] (show_stack) from [<803215c4>] (dump_stack+0xd4/0x118)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601400] [<803215c4>] (dump_stack) from [<80103874>] (bad_page+0xdc/0x12c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601411] [<80103874>] (bad_page) from [<801071a8>] (get_page_from_freelist+0x3bc/0xb5c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601423] [<801071a8>] (get_page_from_freelist) from [<80107c38>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x150/0x9e0)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601434] [<80107c38>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask) from [<8012ea4c>] (handle_mm_fault+0xe0c/0x112c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601443] [<8012ea4c>] (handle_mm_fault) from [<805bc808>] (do_page_fault+0x340/0x3b4)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601452] [<805bc808>] (do_page_fault) from [<800091e8>] (do_DataAbort+0x48/0xc4)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601461] [<800091e8>] (do_DataAbort) from [<805bc0e4>] (__dabt_usr+0x44/0x60)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601464] Exception stack(0xa827bfb0 to 0xa827bff8)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601470] bfa0:                                     03201000 00000000 0000c7f0 00000000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601478] bfc0: 7166e154 0003d800 0003d800 7166e148 00000400 00000002 00000005 02f1e600
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.601485] bfe0: 00000000 7166e130 00000000 76f5b0dc 20000010 ffffffff
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612635] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000004
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612645] pgd = a8220000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612660] [00000004] *pgd=2837e831, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612672] Internal error: Oops: 17 [#1] SMP ARM
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612742] Modules linked in: bnep bluetooth ppp_deflate zlib_deflate bsd_comp ppp_async crc_ccitt ppp_generic slhc cfg80211 rfkill sg option usb_wwan usbserial snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_timer snd bcm2835_gpiomem spi_bcm2835 bcm2835_wdt lirc_rpi(C) uio_pdrv_genirq uio lirc_dev rc_core i2c_dev fuse ipv6
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612755] CPU: 1 PID: 1318 Comm: CompositorTileW Tainted: G    B    C      4.4.34-v7+ #930
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612759] Hardware name: BCM2709
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612763] task: a8365c00 ti: a827a000 task.ti: a827a000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612787] PC is at get_pfnblock_flags_mask+0x5c/0x68
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612792] LR is at 0x0
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612798] pc : [<8010599c>]    lr : [<00000000>]    psr: 20000013
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612798] sp : a827bd90  ip : 00000000  fp : a827bd9c
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612803] r10: b9802a00  r9 : 00000010  r8 : 00000011
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612808] r7 : 00000000  r6 : 808c4f40  r5 : 00000001  r4 : ba01d298
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612812] r3 : 00000007  r2 : 00000009  r1 : 00000001  r0 : 00000014
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612820] Flags: nzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612825] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 2822006a  DAC: 00000055
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612830] Process CompositorTileW (pid: 1318, stack limit = 0xa827a210)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612835] Stack: (0xa827bd90 to 0xa827c000)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612845] bd80:                                     a827bddc a827bda0 80105f00 8010594c
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612853] bda0: 80150904 800d989c 808c5380 000034f6 a827be28 ba01d298 ba01d274 00000000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612861] bdc0: a827be28 805c0e5c a827a000 b9802a00 a827be14 a827bde0 801060a8 80105e74
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612869] bde0: 0000003e 808c8c20 0000003e ba01d2bc 0000003e 00000000 9acce0f4 808c4f40
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612877] be00: 0000003e b9802a00 a827be5c a827be18 8010ea9c 8010604c 00000000 00000003
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612886] be20: 808c4f40 60000013 ba01d2d0 ba01c9d0 00000000 0000003e ba01d2bc 9acce0f4
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612894] be40: 0000003e 9acce000 aff45c00 00000000 a827be84 a827be60 8013eebc 8010e890
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612902] be60: 7f000000 00000000 0321d000 031d0000 00000000 a827beb8 a827befc a827be88
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612911] be80: 8012d5bc 8013ee60 00000000 b62078c0 aff45c00 00000000 a82c3c60 031d0000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612919] bea0: 0321d000 7f000000 00000000 0000003e 00000400 9acce000 a827bee4 a827bec8
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612927] bec0: 80130ca8 801281d4 a8365c00 a827bf3c aff45c00 031d0000 031d0000 0321d000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612937] bee0: 0321d000 00000004 a82c3c60 a827a000 a827bfa4 a827bf00 8013c388 8012d4a4
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612945] bf00: b9f73dc0 b62078c0 b60281c0 aff45c00 00000000 a8365ee8 8013be38 a827bf40
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612953] bf20: 00000000 80049aa0 a827bf4c a827bf38 a827a000 00000000 00000000 a82c3c60
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612961] bf40: a827bf40 a827bf40 a827bf48 a827bf48 a827bf50 a827bf50 a827bfb0 00000000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612969] bf60: a827a000 00000002 a827a010 00000000 a827bfb0 031d0000 0004d000 031d0000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612978] bf80: 0004d000 02cdf170 000000dc 8000fd08 a827a000 00000000 00000000 a827bfa8
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612986] bfa0: 8000fb40 8013bf60 031d0000 0004d000 031d0000 0004d000 00000004 000050cc
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.612994] bfc0: 031d0000 0004d000 02cdf170 000000dc 0000000f 0000003e 000fffff 0332e510
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.613002] bfe0: 02a1f6b4 7166f47c 0073cf61 74c86f4c 20000010 031d0000 00000000 00000000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.613038] [<8010599c>] (get_pfnblock_flags_mask) from [<80105f00>] (free_hot_cold_page+0x98/0x1d8)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.613053] [<80105f00>] (free_hot_cold_page) from [<801060a8>] (free_hot_cold_page_list+0x68/0xec)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.613070] [<801060a8>] (free_hot_cold_page_list) from [<8010ea9c>] (release_pages+0x218/0x264)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.613082] [<8010ea9c>] (release_pages) from [<8013eebc>] (free_pages_and_swap_cache+0x68/0x94)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.613095] [<8013eebc>] (free_pages_and_swap_cache) from [<8012d5bc>] (zap_page_range+0x124/0x198)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.613111] [<8012d5bc>] (zap_page_range) from [<8013c388>] (SyS_madvise+0x434/0x6a4)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.613127] [<8013c388>] (SyS_madvise) from [<8000fb40>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x1c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.613138] Code: e1a01101 e201001f e1a012a1 e0602002 (e79e0101) 
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.613147] ---[ end trace c7a89ede4f5b550c ]---

Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631440] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000004
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631452] pgd = 9acc8000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631473] [00000004] *pgd=1ac46831, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631489] Internal error: Oops: 17 [#2] SMP ARM
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631606] Modules linked in: bnep bluetooth ppp_deflate zlib_deflate bsd_comp ppp_async crc_ccitt ppp_generic slhc cfg80211 rfkill sg option usb_wwan usbserial snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_timer snd bcm2835_gpiomem spi_bcm2835 bcm2835_wdt lirc_rpi(C) uio_pdrv_genirq uio lirc_dev rc_core i2c_dev fuse ipv6
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631622] CPU: 0 PID: 5971 Comm: CompositorTileW Tainted: G    B D  C      4.4.34-v7+ #930
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631627] Hardware name: BCM2709
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631635] task: 9ac21140 ti: a8388000 task.ti: a8388000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631659] PC is at __wake_up_bit+0x18/0x50
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631669] LR is at unlock_page+0x40/0x44
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631677] pc : [<80063754>]    lr : [<800feb78>]    psr: 60000113
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631677] sp : a8389de8  ip : a8389e08  fp : a8389e04
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631682] r10: 9adf8228  r9 : aff45340  r8 : 9adf04d0
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631690] r7 : 9adf8000  r6 : 6a68a000  r5 : 00000200  r4 : ba01d958
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631696] r3 : 00000000  r2 : 00000000  r1 : ba01d958  r0 : 00000000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631705] Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631711] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 1acc806a  DAC: 00000055
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631719] Process CompositorTileW (pid: 5971, stack limit = 0xa8388210)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631725] Stack: (0xa8389de8 to 0xa838a000)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631736] 9de0:                   a8389e1c a8389df8 8012dc38 800feb6c a8389e1c a8389e08
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631746] 9e00: 800feb78 80063748 00000010 a82b136c a8389ea4 a8389e20 8012e5c0 800feb44
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631757] 9e20: 00000001 00000000 f301080e 00000002 a8389e5c a8389e40 8044358c 80442e34
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631765] 9e40: a8389e5c a8389e50 800168f4 000002ec 0000008a 00000040 8031f2f4 ba01d958
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631774] 9e60: 80864100 005b6b3d a8389eac 80130ca8 6a68a000 9ac21140 a8389ea4 a8389fb0
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631781] 9e80: 9ac21140 00000817 6a68a000 aff45340 aff45378 00000055 a8389efc a8389ea8
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631790] 9ea0: 805bc808 8012dc4c 80071bc8 800746c0 80098634 8009677c 808c80f8 808c8114
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631797] 9ec0: b9880f00 00000000 00000800 00000200 b9880f5c 808695c4 00000817 805bc4c8
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631805] 9ee0: 6a68a000 a8389fb0 0000002d 0000010e a8389fac a8389f00 800091e8 805bc4d4
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631815] 9f00: b9880f00 60000193 00000000 00000000 01400000 00000000 00000016 0000010e
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631823] 9f20: a8389f4c a8389f30 8007d4fc 800d99c8 b9f66dc0 8085e4ec 00000000 00000000
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631831] 9f40: a8389f64 a8389f50 800296bc 8007d488 80346eb4 8085e4ec a8389f8c a8389f68
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631839] 9f60: 80071320 80029624 a8389fb0 01628e40 00000030 ffffffff 10c5387d 10c5387d
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631847] 9f80: a8389f9c 01628e80 20000030 01628e80 20000030 ffffffff 10c5387d 10c5387d
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631855] 9fa0: 00000000 a8389fb0 805bc0e4 800091ac 6a689f68 6b24f8c8 00000027 0000010e
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631863] 9fc0: 6a68a000 6b250ae4 6b24f9f8 6b250270 6a67e008 0000002d 0000010e 000002c5
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631871] 9fe0: 6b25013c 70e6e22c 6b2509b0 01628e80 20000030 ffffffff ffbcbcbc ffbcbcbc
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631894] [<80063754>] (__wake_up_bit) from [<800feb78>] (unlock_page+0x40/0x44)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631909] [<800feb78>] (unlock_page) from [<8012e5c0>] (handle_mm_fault+0x980/0x112c)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631923] [<8012e5c0>] (handle_mm_fault) from [<805bc808>] (do_page_fault+0x340/0x3b4)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631937] [<805bc808>] (do_page_fault) from [<800091e8>] (do_DataAbort+0x48/0xc4)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631950] [<800091e8>] (do_DataAbort) from [<805bc0e4>] (__dabt_usr+0x44/0x60)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631953] Exception stack(0xa8389fb0 to 0xa8389ff8)
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631961] 9fa0:                                     6a689f68 6b24f8c8 00000027 0000010e
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631971] 9fc0: 6a68a000 6b250ae4 6b24f9f8 6b250270 6a67e008 0000002d 0000010e 000002c5
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631977] 9fe0: 6b25013c 70e6e22c 6b2509b0 01628e80 20000030 ffffffff
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631986] Code: e24cb004 e24dd010 e52de004 e8bd4000 (e590e004) 
Mar  7 09:00:08 raspberrypi kernel: [60212.631993] ---[ end trace c7a89ede4f5b550d ]---
```

I'm not able to reproduce the bug and I need to if I want to be able to solve it. If you have any idea to hard test the system, please feel free to tell me.

Comment: The log tells something about "kernel null pointers", which seems to be a problem with how Electron renders HTML. I'll try to reproduce it on my RasPi. I think I had something similar a long time ago...

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Happy to know that someone else already had something similar! If you have a part of code that can reproduce the bug easily, please share it to me! :) Thank you!